# @nuxtjs/i18n locales changing after refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I have an application where I try to put the language management but I face a difficulty.
I'm on the latest version of `@nuxtjs/i18n`. When I change language, my URl changes, my labels change, everything is fine. When I refresh my page, however, the system reverts to the old language.

Here is my conf:

```
[
 '@nuxtjs/i18n',
       {
           locales,
           defaultLocale,
           lazy: true,
           langDir: 'locales/',
           vueI18n: {
               fallbackLocale: defaultLocale,
           },
       },
   ],
   ['~/.build/merge-and-compare-locales.js', { defaultLocale }],
```

```
export const locales = [
    {
        code: 'en',
        file: 'en.json',
    },
    {
        code: 'fr',
        file: 'fr.json',
    },
]

export const defaultLocale = 'fr'
```

What more do I need to do to make it keep the language before refresh?

I specify that I use this method to change the language:

```
changeLocale(code: string) {
    this.$i18n.setLocale(code)
},
```

Locally it works fine. On the other hand on any other environment it does not work, the refresh makes return to the default language

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem and it's come from ssr...
inside your store/index you should have a nsi (nuxt server init) function
something like this.

```
async nuxtServerInit(ssrContext: Context) 
{
    if (this.$i18n.locale==='ar') {
      ssrContext.redirect("/ar");
    }
    else if (this.$i18n.locale === 'fa')
    {
      ssrContext.redirect('/')
    }
}
```